# calling a prototype function with on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I new to prototyping and have a function that I am trying to call 'loadParticipants()' with an onchange event.  The problem I'm running into is that if I use

```
$("#mySelector").on("change",function())
```

To call this function

```
 TransferParticipantsForm.prototype.loadParticipants = function()
{
 // my code here
 }
```

The problem i'm running into is that if I call the function from my onchange event, I lose my 'this'.

Is there anyway for me to call that function without losing my context?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code is not valid JS currently.

Comment: Can you use `.bind()`?